# zsh messing up new-line and/or input echoing

Tags: zsh, oh-my-zsh

**(EDIT)**: The description below are two unrelated behaviors: one is behaving as expected, the other is an actual issue inrelated to `zsh`. There is no new-line regression in `zsh`.

---

I've migrated to `zsh` from `bash` in OSX (Catalina). I also use `oh-my-zsh`. I've noticed recently the new line character or the echo of the input is sometimes missing. I've found at least two cases:

1. using `time`: (first invocation uses `/bin/zsh`)

```
~
▶ time ls
 1pwd.bkp       Downloads   Pictures   'VirtualBox VMs'   go                pf-docs.txt       tools
 Applications   Library     Public      bin               istio-lean.yaml   plugins.sbt.bkp   wip
 Desktop        Movies      SWIFT       docs.txt          main.txt          project           workshop
 Documents      Music       Snapshots   git               normal.yml        todo
gls --color=tty  0.00s user 0.00s system 62% cpu 0.009 total

~
▶ /bin/sh
# time ls
1pwd.bkp        Downloads       Pictures        VirtualBox VMs  go              pf-docs.txt     tools
Applications    Library         Public          bin             istio-lean.yaml plugins.sbt.bkp wip
Desktop         Movies          SWIFT           docs.txt        main.txt        project         workshop
Documents       Music           Snapshots       git             normal.yml      todo

real    0m0.011s
user    0m0.003s
sys     0m0.005s
#
```

2. using `sbt`/`g8`: (first invocation uses `/bin/zsh`)

```
~/wip/deleteme
▶ sbt new scala/scala-seed.g8
[info] Loading settings for project global-plugins from build.sbt ...
[info] Loading global plugins from /Users/ignasi/.sbt/1.0/plugins
[info] Set current project to deleteme (in build file:/Users/ignasi/wip/deleteme/)
[info] Set current project to deleteme (in build file:/Users/ignasi/wip/deleteme/)

A minimal Scala project.

name [Scala Seed Project]:
Template applied in /Users/ignasi/wip/deleteme/./myprojectzsh


~/wip/deleteme
▶ /bin/sh
sh: _direnv_hook: command not found
%n@%m %1~ %# sbt new scala/scala-seed.g8
[info] Loading settings for project global-plugins from build.sbt ...
[info] Loading global plugins from /Users/ignasi/.sbt/1.0/plugins
[info] Set current project to deleteme (in build file:/Users/ignasi/wip/deleteme/)
[info] Set current project to deleteme (in build file:/Users/ignasi/wip/deleteme/)

A minimal Scala project.

name [Scala Seed Project]: MyProjectBinSh

Template applied in /Users/ignasi/wip/deleteme/./myprojectbinsh

# ls
```

Note how the invocation under `/bin/zsh` doesn't echo the user input (`myprojectzsh`) after `name [...]:`:

```
name [Scala Seed Project]:
Template applied in /Users/ignasi/wip/deleteme/./myprojectzsh
```

and even is missing a blank newline.

I haven't ruled out the issue is actually two different problems in `time` and `sbt`/`g8` which happen to have the same symptoms.

PS:Things get even a bit weird when I try `time echo hello` in `/bin/zsh`:

```
▶ time echo hello
hello

~
▶
```

Where the `time` report is not even printed (?).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing messed up in 1. `time` is built-in shell command in zsh (and also in bash). You can check for yourself

```
which time
```

Behaviour and output style of zsh *time* is different than the one in the bash. You can run "real" binary implementation of `time`: `/usr/bin/time command` and see it will produce yet another differently formatted output.

Also the reason why `time echo hello` has no output is that in zsh `time` has no effect on built-in commands like echo. If you really want to, you can force execution of subshell by using parenthesis like this `time (echo hello)`, but ultimately this doesn't make any sense -- you are measuring time of subshell life, not the echo itself.

Comment: Thanks @rcwnd_nz, this seems to indicate I'm facing two different issues with similar symptoms. I'll follow up on the `sbt` issue with their maintainers.

Comment: Apparently the `sbt` issue is unrelated to `zsh`: https://github.com/sbt/util/pull/233